# SimpleXMLElement Object response for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, simplexml

Im trying to return a list of contacts from the Xero API however when getting the response back from there api i cannot run the array through a for each loop.

when trying to loop through nothing is displayed, has anyone had this problem in the past?

im trying to loop through to put each contact within a row inside a table.

if i run

```
pr($contacts->Contacts[0]);
```

it returns the list of contacts however it wont display anything with the for loop below

This is my for loop

```
foreach($contacts->Contacts[0] as $item) {
echo $item['Id'];
echo $item['filepath'];
}
```

this is the array returned

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[Id] => 0dcda838-d354-4674-b6eb-d788e166b8dd
[Status] => OK
[ProviderName] => TestIntergration
[DateTimeUTC] => 2017-09-18T01:42:30.7361585Z
[Contacts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Contact] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [ContactID] => 0ae2c0f4-cae9-4431-ab6b-52554f1c7c69
                        [ContactStatus] => ACTIVE
                        [Name] => Steve Buscemi
                        [Addresses] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => STREET
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => POBOX
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Phones] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Phone] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DDI
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DEFAULT
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => FAX
                                            )

                                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => MOBILE
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2017-08-30T08:14:03.88
                        [IsSupplier] => false
                        [IsCustomer] => true
                        [HasAttachments] => false
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [ContactID] => ab8a9286-740e-4246-876c-9fcac558d600
                        [ContactStatus] => ACTIVE
                        [Name] => Martin Hudson
                        [Addresses] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => STREET
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => POBOX
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Phones] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Phone] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DDI
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DEFAULT
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => FAX
                                            )

                                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => MOBILE
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2017-08-30T08:20:03.263
                        [IsSupplier] => false
                        [IsCustomer] => true
                        [HasAttachments] => false
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [ContactID] => 463e9f23-d1a1-4d74-b19e-041142c8fd34
                        [ContactStatus] => ACTIVE
                        [Name] => Orlena Greenville
                        [Addresses] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => STREET
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => POBOX
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Phones] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Phone] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DDI
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DEFAULT
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => FAX
                                            )

                                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => MOBILE
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2017-09-01T07:56:32.667
                        [IsSupplier] => false
                        [IsCustomer] => false
                        [HasAttachments] => false
                    )

                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [ContactID] => b75bfe5b-cc6e-45ee-b0a1-feafe866088d
                        [ContactStatus] => ACTIVE
                        [Name] => asdfasdfasdf454
                        [Addresses] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Address] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => STREET
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [AddressType] => POBOX
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [Phones] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Phone] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DDI
                                            )

                                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => DEFAULT
                                            )

                                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => FAX
                                            )

                                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [PhoneType] => MOBILE
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2017-09-04T10:34:52.93
                        [IsSupplier] => false
                        [IsCustomer] => false
                        [HasAttachments] => false
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Code used to get the passed data

```
$response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', $XeroOAuth->url('Contacts', 'core'), array());
if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {
 $contacts = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']);           
 pr($contacts);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the original XML instead.

Comment: this is the original xml, this is whats passed from the xero api

Comment: XML looks like `<doc><contacts><contact>...</contact></contacts></doc>`.

Comment: not sure how to get that, i have updated the question with the code used to return the info from the api